# How to apply Search view in List View Activity retrieving data from firebase?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, searchview

I want filter `firebase` data to this list view How can do that

```
 seachView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String mQuery) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


                mQuery = mDatabaseRef.orderByChild("Username").equalTo(newText);
               return false;

            }
        });
```